# More rigorous presentations of Martin-Löf type theory?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory

I'm enjoying reading Martin-Löf's 1972 paper "An Intuitionistic Theory of Types" for the first time (this constitutes my first-ever exposure to Martin-Löf's papers), but at times find the "formal" rules still not as formal as they could get. For instance, consider the term-fromation rule $\Sigma$-elimination on page 138 (I don't know how to code the natural deduction line, so I awkwardly express that here using the 'if ... then' format):

$\bullet$ If $x\in A$, $y\in B[x]$, $c\in (\Sigma x\in A) B[x]$ and $d[x,y]\in C[(x,y)]$ then $E(c,(\lambda x)(\lambda y) d[x,y])\in C(c)$.

It's not specified in the rule what $C$ and $d$ are exactly, but the informal discussions prior to this say that $C$ is a function that assigns which to an arbitrary object of type $(\Sigma x\in A) B(x)$ assigns a type, and $d$ is a function of type $(\Pi x\in A)(\Pi y\in B(x))C(x,y)$.

Given this, wouldn't a more rigorous presentation of the rule be something like the following:

$\bullet$ If $C\in ((\Sigma x\in A) B[x])\to V$, $d\in (\Pi x\in A)(\Pi y\in B(x))C[(x,y)]$, $x\in A$, $y\in B[x]$, $c\in (\Sigma x\in A) B[x]$ and $d[x,y]\in C[(x,y)]$ then $E(c,(\lambda x)(\lambda y) d[x,y])\in C(c)$,

where $V$ is the universe of small types?

Question: am I correct about the point above? Also, are there more rigorous presentations of Martin-Löf's type theory (perhaps more recent ones?) where such issues are considered?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fwiw I think MLTT got updated in the 80s. Are you aware of this repository https://github.com/michaelt/martin-lof ? See the 1984 book.

Comment: Have you tried the Appendix of the HoTT Book? It is rather terse, but maybe useful

Comment: You may want to look into Jacob’s book Categorical Logic and Type Theory. They look at every detail (twice) and in the last chapter there is a dependent type theory plus categorical semantics.